# PHP - How to generate a different hash for the same string?

Tags: php, hash, decode, encode

I need to input for example a number, for example "1234"

and output for example "FDRG-DRGB-RDSD" and if I give as input again the "1234" I need that the output generated is different, for example "GGDF-FRRF-DSED" and these two hash strings need to decode:

```
"FDRG-DRGB-RDSD" -> "1234"

"GGDF-FRRF-DSED" -> "1234"
```

This is possible out of the box? Can someone give some clues on how to achieve this with PHP?

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ ?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. The point of a hash is that (a) You always get the same result for the same input and (b) You can't decode it. What are you actually trying to do? Hashes don't appear to be the right solution.

Comment: @Quentin don't forget that's why you salt them so that they *don't* always give the same hash output because that's a security flaw

Comment: Looking for a `Hash Map` maybe?

Comment: Generally encode and decode is possible using base64_encode/decode. But it always return you same string.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I think the best solution for this is to create an hash table using uuid's and associate them with the serial number. For each serial number I will have 1000+ uuid's. There is better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Hashing is One way and you can not decode hash value. 
"1234" -> "FDRG-DRGB-RDSD" will remain same for all attempts.

You can try an encryption method with seeding and have different seed while encryption and during decryption use respective seed to get original string. Something like below:

```
encrypt -> "1234", "seed1" => FDRG-DRGB-RDSD
encrypt -> "1234", "seed2" => GGDF-FRRF-DSED

decrypt -> GGDF-FRRF-DSED, "seed2" -> 1234
decrypt -> FDRG-DRGB-RDSD, "seed1" -> 1234
```

you can pick best encryption mechanism based on your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I will create an hash table using uuid's and associate them with the serial number. For each serial number I will have 1000+ uuid's.